# Make two collectionViews responsible for make navigationBar smaller with scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have two separate views that there is a `collectionView` in each of them.
Both views have the same top and button constraint anchor

The width is the same size of the screen bound

```
private lazy var screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

and here is the constraints

```
    friendsCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    friendsCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    friendsCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenSize).isActive = true
    
    friendsCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: discoveryCollectionView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    friendsViewTrillingAnchor = friendsCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
    friendsViewTrillingAnchor.isActive = true

    discoveryCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    discoveryCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    discoveryCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenSize).isActive = true

    discoveryViewLeadingAnchor = discoveryCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: -screenSize)
    discoveryViewLeadingAnchor.isActive = true
```

And there is segmented control to active each of them. I made an animation that they moving to the left and right screen to make space for another one- see screenshot

when I press each segmented button, I call `handleFeedsTransition` function

```
private func handleFeedsTransition(with feedsType: FeedsType ) {
    
    switch feedsType {
        
    case .discovery:
        self.feedsType = .discovery
        handleFeedsTransitionAnimation()
        
    case .friends:
        self.feedsType = .friends
        handleFeedsTransitionAnimation()
    }
}


private func handleFeedsTransitionAnimation() {
    
    switch feedsType {
        
    case .discovery:

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { [weak self] in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.discoveryCollectionView.isHidden = false
            
            
            this.discoveryViewLeadingAnchor.constant = 0
            this.friendsViewTrillingAnchor.constant = this.screenSize
            this.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            
            this.friendsCollectionView.isHidden = true
        })
        
    case .friends:
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { [weak self] in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            
            this.friendsCollectionView.isHidden = false
            
            this.discoveryViewLeadingAnchor.constant = -this.screenSize
            this.friendsViewTrillingAnchor.constant = 0
            this.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.discoveryCollectionView.isHidden = true
        })
    }
}
```

[image]

And here is the navigation bar configuration

```
   navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
   navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

So there is a simple issue, I want to both views make the navigation bar smaller when scrolling, but when I add them in `view.subView`always the first one does it, and the second one will not make the navigation bar smaller

here

```
 view.addSubview(todoCollectionView)
 view.addSubview(taskCollectionView)
```

only `todoCollectionView` does it, and if I change their order `taskCollectionView` only does it

Any way to fix it? Thank you so much

Comment: I have a thought or two... but it would be ***much*** easier if you post a [mre] (somewhere like GitHub).

Comment: dear @DonMag, thank you so much for your help, I added more code in the first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick note - As we probably know, in order to use the automatic large-title expand/collapse display, the **first subview** must be a scroll view (`UICollectionView`, `UITableView`, `UIScrollView`, etc).

So, I thought... to go from "discovery" to "friends" let's just swap the z-order with:

```
view.sendSubviewToBack(friendsCollectionView)
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Apparently, the navigation bar functionality is determined *when the view is added*. So, all that accomplished was to eliminate the functionality from **both** collection views :(

For one approach to solving this, we can:

- remove both collection views with `.removeFromSuperview()`
- re-add them with:

  - `view.insertSubview(friendsCollectionView, at: 0)`
  - `view.insertSubview(discoveryCollectionView, at: 1)`
- reset their constraints
- animate their positions

Here's a quick example...

First, simple single-label cell:

```
class SimpleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        label.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

and an example view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var discoveryCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var friendsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var discoveryViewLeadingAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!

    let segCtrl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Discovery", "Friends"])

    @objc func segChanged(_ sender: Any?) {

        guard let segCtrl = sender as? UISegmentedControl else { return }
        
        // save the current "position" of discoveryCollectionView
        let curConstant: CGFloat = discoveryViewLeadingAnchor.constant
        
        discoveryCollectionView.removeFromSuperview()
        friendsCollectionView.removeFromSuperview()
        
        if segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            view.insertSubview(friendsCollectionView, at: 0)
            view.insertSubview(discoveryCollectionView, at: 1)
        } else {
            view.insertSubview(discoveryCollectionView, at: 0)
            view.insertSubview(friendsCollectionView, at: 1)
        }

        // we removed and re-added the collection views,
        // so we need to reset the constraints
        setCommonConstraints(discoveryLeading: curConstant)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.discoveryViewLeadingAnchor.constant = curConstant == 0.0 ? -self.view.frame.width : 0.0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
        
    }
    
    func setCommonConstraints(discoveryLeading c: CGFloat) {
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        // these constraints must be set each time the colletion views
        //  are added as subviews
        
        discoveryViewLeadingAnchor = discoveryCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: c)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            discoveryCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            discoveryCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segCtrl.topAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            friendsCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: discoveryCollectionView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            friendsCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: discoveryCollectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            discoveryCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor),
            friendsCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor),
            
            friendsCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: discoveryCollectionView.trailingAnchor),

            discoveryViewLeadingAnchor,
            
        ])

    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.title = "Swap Testing"
        
        navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        
        let discoveryFL = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        discoveryFL.scrollDirection = .vertical
        discoveryFL.minimumLineSpacing = 12.0
        discoveryFL.minimumInteritemSpacing = 12.0
        
        let friendsFL = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        friendsFL.scrollDirection = .vertical
        friendsFL.minimumLineSpacing = 12.0
        friendsFL.minimumInteritemSpacing = 12.0

        // let's make the item height's different, just to confirm the functionality
        discoveryFL.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 60.0)
        friendsFL.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)

        discoveryCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: discoveryFL)
        friendsCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: friendsFL)
        
        discoveryCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        discoveryCollectionView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        friendsCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        friendsCollectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

        segCtrl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(discoveryCollectionView)
        view.addSubview(friendsCollectionView)
        
        view.addSubview(segCtrl)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // let's put the segmented control at the bottom
            segCtrl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            segCtrl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            segCtrl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])

        setCommonConstraints(discoveryLeading: 0.0)
        
        discoveryCollectionView.register(SimpleCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "c")
        friendsCollectionView.register(SimpleCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "c")

        discoveryCollectionView.dataSource = self
        discoveryCollectionView.delegate = self
        
        friendsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        friendsCollectionView.delegate = self
        
        segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        segCtrl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
    }
    
    // so we can set the cell item width to the view width
    var cvWidth: CGFloat = 0
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        // only want to call this when the frame changes
        if cvWidth != discoveryCollectionView.frame.width {
            cvWidth = discoveryCollectionView.frame.width
            if let fl = discoveryCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                fl.itemSize.width = discoveryCollectionView.frame.width
            }
            if let fl = friendsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                fl.itemSize.width = friendsCollectionView.frame.width
            }
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // let's use different number of items, just to make sure everything is working right
        return collectionView == discoveryCollectionView ? 20 : 30
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! SimpleCell
        if collectionView == discoveryCollectionView {
            cell.label.text = "Discovery: \(indexPath.item)"
            cell.label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        } else {
            cell.label.text = "Friends: \(indexPath.item)"
            cell.label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        }
        return cell

    }
    
}
```